# How to have multiple spring boot applications in one repository?

Tags: spring-boot

We currently have several small code bases which are all using spring boot and have some duplicate code. We would like to bring these into the same repository and are just looking for the best approach to do this. We have been looking at either have one src/main which contains all of the code and then we have different mains that can be called to run ([based on this tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring#configuration-options)) or having separate modules in the same repository and then having one parent module which has the shared logic.

Any experience from doing something similar would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar development environment setup for 8 months by now and our team is not a pretty big one (only 7 persons) and we do pretty fine.

Firstly, I want to make it clear that it has not much to do with Spring Boot, it's all about your building and dependency management technology, in my case Maven.

**Sharing dependencies and properties**:
You can use parent project as a container to sub projects which share same common dependencies and properties.

Your container maven project packaging must be `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.But notice that any dependencies appears in this file will be inherited in the sub projects, so keep the necessary common dependencies only, otherwise you will need to have it in the sub project maven file with a long list of excluded artifacts.

**Sharing code modules**:
You can separate your common code in maven project also under the parent project(container) and add it as a provided dependency to whatever project you want.

**Please consider this structure**:

```
/*parent project pom file : may have common spring starter dependencies and any other dependencies will be used all over the modules*/

<modules>
        <module>backend</module> <!-- backend will contain deployable modules which may reuse nodules of reusable code in commons module -->
        <module>frontend</module> <!-- backend will contain deployable modules which may reuse nodules of reusable code in commons module -->
        <module>commons</module> <!-- reusable code modules -->
</modules>

//backend module pom file : may have common spring starter dependencies and any other dependencies will be used all over backend modules

    <modules>
        <module>account-service</module> <!-- deployable account service module -->
        <module>ledger-service</module> <!-- deployable ledger service module -->
        <module>backend-commons</module> <!-- reusable code modules to be used in backend services modules -->
    </modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage from merging separate projects into one repository. It'll create mess in your repository history and you will have a lot of problems with branch handling.

Just keep using separate repository for every spring boot project + have common logic is separate project (as well as repository). That project will be versioned/built/deployed separately into your artifact repository. Your Spring Boot services will be using as JAR dependency.